# How do I get a value from an attribute?

Tags: c#, enums, attributes

I am trying to use an enum as a parameter in an attribute, and use the type of the enum to determine stuff in my code, however I struggle to get the actual type of the enum.

Here is my enum:

```
    public enum DataTypes
{
    ShortText,
    LongText,
    Number,
    Boolean,
    Image,
    DatePicker,
    RichText,
    Content,
    DateTimePicker,
    ProductStatus,
    DeliveryMethod

}
```

Here is the Attribute:

```
    public class DataType : Attribute
{
    public DataTypes Type { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, here is where I apply them:

```
[DataType(Type=DataTypes.ShortText)]
    public string store { get; set; }
```

How would I get the attribute from the PropertyInfo to return DataTypes.ShortText?

Comment: You have to retrieve the attribute instance (via reflection). Then you just get the `Type` property value. What have you tried? What _specifically_ are you having trouble getting to work? Please fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you're having, and so that it includes a clear, detailed explanation of what that problem is.

Comment: I suggested/edited the question title because it's not really about `enum`. The answer is the same if the value you're trying to get from the attribute is an `enum`, `int`, `string`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to get the property. In its simplest form it could look like this:

```
var method = typeof(SomeClass).GetMethod("store");
```

`GetMethod` returns an instance of [`MethodInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

Then you can retrieve the attribute if it's present:

```
var attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute<DataType>();
```

`GetCustomAttribute` will return null if there's no attribute of that type. But if that attribute is present, `GetCustomAttribute` returns it.

```
if (attribute != null)
{
    var myDataType = attribute.Type;
}
```